# python `wave`: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' in Python

Tags: python

I'm having a trouble running the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import wave
import struct

amplitude = 30000
frequency = 100
duration = 3
fs = 44100
num_samples = duration * fs

num_channels = 1
sampwidth = 2
num_frames = num_samples
comptype = "NONE"
compname = "not compressed"

t = np.linspace(0, duration, num_samples, endpoint = False)
x = amplitude * np.cos(2*np.pi * frequency * t )

wav_file = wave.open("One_Life.wav",'w')
wav_file.setparams((num_channels, sampwidth,fs,num_frames,comptype,compname))
for s in x:
  wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h',int(s)))

  wav_file.close()
```

The error I'm getting is as follow:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I'm unable to figure this one out, can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `wav_file.close()` out of the loop

```
for s in x:
    wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h',int(s)))

wav_file.close()
```

`writeframes()` has `_file.write` internally, but you are closing the file, setting it to `None`. From `wave.py`

```
def writeframes(self, data):
    self.writeframesraw(data)
    #...

def writeframesraw(self, data):
    #...
    self._file.write(data)
    #...

def close(self):
    self._file = None
    #...
```

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: @Sheng What are you referring to?

Comment: @Sheng This is the source code, I added the relevant code to the question to show the process. You are using `writeframes()` which call `writeframesraw()` which use the variable `self._file`. When you call `close()` `self._file` is set to `None`.

Comment: So I need to find wave.py?

Comment: @Sheng No, all you need to do is move `wav_file.close()` outside the loop. See the first code block in my answer.

Comment: OH.I understand.